# How to tail the last line of multiple files using "tail -1 */filename"

Tags: linux, bash, tail, head

```
tail */filename
```

works, but

```
tail -1 */filename
```

doesn't. Why is this? And is there a 1 liner to perform this task without loops?

```
head -1 */filename
```

works for some strange reason.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but can you explain why it does that?

Comment: Also, what's the best way to tail and list them in natural numeric order, like the way ls -v does. I think just using tail */filename, directories 1, 10, 11, 12, etc would be listed together, while I want 1, 2, 3, 4, ... to be listed together. Thanks.

Comment: `head` and `tail` are just designed differently; `tail` requires `-n`, `head` uses `-n` for any number `n`. You should post your other request as a separate question, to make it easier for others to find in the future.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

While `head` works with `-1` on multiple files, `tail` does not. But it works with the `-n` argument instead:

```
tail -n 1 */filename
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are still looking for answer please try below one :

Go to the directory in which file are available and execute below command

```
ls -1|while read file; do tail -1 $file; done
```